# Some issues with inheritance and default constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, constructor, struct

I have two structs

```
        template<typename T>
        struct Node{
               T obj;
               Node* next;
               Node* prev;
               Node();
               Node(T a, Node<T>* b=NULL, Node<T>* c=NULL);
        };

        template<typename T>
        struct Monomial : public Node<T>{
               int n;
               Monomial(T coeff = 0, int p = 0) : Node<T>(coeff){ n=p; }
        };
```

The compiler tells me that I am doing something wrong but I can't figure it out?

I tried to do this in the `main` function:

```
         Monomial<int> *m1;
         m1->n=5;
         m1->obj=6;
```

and the error message I got was "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'm1' is being used without being initialized."

Comment: what are the error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a pointer doesn't create an object.

```
// Allocate memory for the object and create it.

Monomial<int> *m1 = new Monomial<int>;
m1->n=5;
m1->obj=6;

// When you are done with the object, destroy it and deallocate memory.
delete m1;
```

Alternately create the object on the stack

```
Monomial<int> m1;
m1.n=5;
m1.obj=6;
```

No need to call `new` or `delete`

Comment: @F'OlaYinka You should consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Initialise m1 like this.

```
Monomial<int> *m1 = new Momonial<int>();
```